# What does this assembly language program output?

Tags: assembly, decompilation, c

I have been struggling with this for a long time. I have the following assembly language code:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.bits 32

.global asm0

asm0:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    mov eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
    mov ebx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
    mov eax,ebx
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp 
    ret
```

and **I want to figure out what asm(0xb6, 0xc6) returns**. I've been looking for ASM->C decompilers etc, and I cannot find anything for free. Could someone please help me decipher this? I've been trying for a really long time. I am familiar with C++ and Java programming, so even some sort of tool to convert it would be helpful.

I'm currently reading from this: http://www.godevtool.com/GoasmHelp/newass.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is such a small program so this could be followed without converting it back to C. Let's break it down what happens when it's being called with `asm(0xb6, 0xc6)`.

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
```

Those two lines are what's is called the function prologue. We first save the calling function stack frame (`ebp` is tracking that) and in the second one, we set our function stack frame to be equal to the current stack location.

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
mov ebx, DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
```

The above lines are loading our passed arguments to `eax` and `ebx`. Since in `cdecl` arguments are passed via stack in reverse order, so after those lines in `eax` we will have `0xb6` and `ebx` will be equal to `0xc6`.

```
mov eax, ebx
```

The value from `ebx` is stored in `eax`, thus we drop the need of the first line from the previous fragment. Also since this is the last use of `eax` in this code it can be interpreted as a return value as this is also a convention in `cdecl`. So the return value, in this case, would be `0xc6`.

```
mov esp,ebp
pop ebp
```

This is just bringing back the stack as it was when we enter the function - also called function epilogue.

```
ret
```

And return back to the caller.

Having analyzed that it's just obvious that this function returns the second argument that's being passed to it.

```
int second(int a, int b)
{
    return b;
}
```

You could compile this code to a library and use it from C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned int _test (unsigned int, unsigned int);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%x\n", _test(0xb6, 0xc6));
    return 0;
}
```

and compile it with `gcc -m32 -o run asm.o call.o`.

> ./run 
>   c6

You could verify that it's the case without running it by for example using [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5gAK5m) but since the code that assigns the first value to `eax` and then replaces it with the second is actually not needed - it could just use the second argument from the beginning - it won't be generated even w/o any optimizations.